# Cozy environment for frontend-developers

Tags: flask, virtualenv, frontend

Briefly. There is some site on production. Technologies in use: flask, python. Server is running on apache2 and virtualenv.
The structure on flask project:

- templates (Here are html sripts, python scripts redirect users to this html files )
- static (css and js files)
- python scripts

The problem is in inconvenience for frontend-developer to debug site, because flask requires html code to be in `templates`, css and js to be in static and paths to css must be pointed via templating engine like this:

```
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/index.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Only in this case everything is fine on production and css will be found. So for debugging on local machine frontend-developer must change paths removing the templating engine like this:

```
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

or debug directly on server. Both ways are inappropriate.

The question is how to design cozy environment for frontend developer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to you Server and type:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

It will create a list of all your installed packages and dependencies. Then you can install environment on frontender's machine by

```
pip install virtualenv
```

then go to your project directory

```
virtualenv venv
cd venv/Scripts
activate 
cd ../..
```

and now install all packages from requirements.txt by

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
python <name of main python script>
```

This will create the exact environment like you have on your Server.